# Fixed Intervals for xAxis HighStock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some dynamic data for a stock and need to display them using `HighStock`, which is easy as the example provided on `highcharts` website.

However, I need to set the plot to display fixed X-Axis intervals as

```
9:30, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 1:00 ... 16:00
```

and have dynamic data populated within that boundary. Please guide me in this case.

Comment: Take a look at `tickPositioner` in Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

You can dictate your own positions and intervals.

Comment: Apart of tickPositioner, you need to manipulate [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) param.